# Getting disconnected from OpenVPN server each hour

Tags: openvpn

I am having a rather strange issue with my `OpenVPN` configuration. I am connecting from `Windows 7` with official latest `OpenVPN` client to my `OpenVPN` server (`OpenVPN 2.1.4 i386-redhat-linux-gnu`).

The problem is I am getting disconnected from my `OpenVPN` server exactly after 1 hour and I can't understand what directive/option is reponsible for this. Maybe it's a client issue? I have tried different `Windows` systems and `Windows VPN` clients. The `Linux` clients are working as expected with no disconnections.

Could you please help me to troublshoot this issue? I have tried reading books and googling and some people advise to play with `keepalive` and `reneg-sec` directives. But that does not seem to help.

**OpenVPN server config**

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh1024.pem
server 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0"
client-config-dir ccd
route 192.168.51.0 255.255.255.0
keepalive 60 600
reneg-sec 5000
hand-window 15
tls-auth ta.key 0
comp-lzo
max-clients 50
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 4
crl-verify crl.pem
management localhost 11111
plugin /usr/share/openvpn/plugin/lib/openvpn-auth-pam.so login
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.2.1"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN example.com"
push "dhcp-option SEARCH example.com"
```

**Server log** (isn't the problem in reinit_src=1?)

```
Oct  9 07:23:38 vpn openvpn[19495]: user/192.168.253.20:54568 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Oct  9 07:23:38 vpn openvpn[19495]: user/192.168.253.20:54568 TLS: move_session: dest=TM_LAME_DUCK src=TM_ACTIVE reinit_src=1
Oct  9 07:24:53 vpn openvpn[19495]: user/192.168.253.20:54568 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Oct  9 07:26:08 vpn openvpn[19495]: user/192.168.253.20:54568 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 15 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Oct  9 07:26:08 vpn openvpn[19495]: user/192.168.253.20:54568 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Oct  9 07:26:39 vpn openvpn[19495]: user/192.168.253.20:54568 [UNDEF] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Oct  9 07:26:39 vpn openvpn[19495]: user/192.168.253.20:54568 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, client-instance restarting
```

**Client log**

```
RwrWRwRwRwRwTue Oct 09 07:26:39 2012 us=796000 TLS: soft reset sec=0 bytes=7405621/0 pkts=9459/0
Tue Oct 09 07:26:39 2012 us=600000 ERROR: could not read Auth username from stdin
Tue Oct 09 07:26:39 2012 us=600000 Exiting
Tue Oct 09 07:26:39 2012 us=600000 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe DELETE 192.168.2.1 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.100.150
Tue Oct 09 07:26:39 2012 us=600000 Route deletion via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Tue Oct 09 07:26:39 2012 us=600000 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe DELETE 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 192.168.100.150
Tue Oct 09 07:26:39 2012 us=600000 Route deletion via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Tue Oct 09 07:26:39 2012 us=600000 Closing TUN/TAP interface
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The culprit seems to be your authentication configuration. You are using `plugin /usr/share/openvpn/plugin/lib/openvpn-auth-pam.so login` which would require the client to supply a valid username/password combination to connect. Apparently, this is also required upon rekeying and your OpenVPN client seems unable to request the user name from `stdin` (`ERROR: could not read Auth username from stdin`).

As for the reason why raising reneg-sec in your server configuration does not help matters, this is because the parameter has to be specified in both - the server's and the client's config to be effectively raised above the default of 3600 seconds (which happens to cause the one hour - disconnect you are seeing).

So your options would be to

- use an authentication method which does not require user input (certificates spring to mind)
- troubleshoot why your client is unable to prompt for the user name / password combination after connection establishment
- raise the rekeying period or disable rekeying entirely (which weakens your connection's security, so it surely is only an inferior workaround to your problem)

Comment: You are right, putting reneg-sec to the client.ovpn helped to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 12):

you can try to `reneg-sec 0` in your `server.conf`:

https://duo.com/docs/openvpn

https://tldrify.com/m80

it's quite simple really. Since OpenVPN tries to renegociate a new TLS Session every 3600 secs by default, you'd have to re-authenticate each time, using a new OTP. To avoid this kind of behaviour, it's just a matter of telling openvpn to never renegociate a TLS session and keep the existing one alive, if you combine `keepalive` directive and `reneg-sec 0`, you're going to have a stable connection, with no renegociation whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced a similar effect when I added the 'auth-nocache' option to my client configuration. I use certificates AND a username + password combination to authenticate.

A few times I noticed in the connection logs that openvpn reported the following warning:

> WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the
>   auth-nocache option to prevent this

So I thought I'll just add this option and see what happens. Well, the above warning does go away, but after an hour a dialog box popped up, asking me for my username and password.

I noticed that the above configuration by Andrew doesn't contain this option so I'm a little puzzled as to why it doesn't cache the password. Maybe this is because I'm using a newer version of openvpn or maybe it can be set on the server config to push this option to the client.

This was seen on: OpenVPN 2.2.1-8+deb7u2 with OpenVPN GUI v5 for Windows.

Comment: I have to generate a file using openvpn and then add the auth-nocache option. Now is working perfectly. File generated can be used as

Comment: @ingcarlos Great to hear it's working for you. Happy vpn-ing.

Comment: +1 Absolutley right, I faced the same problem after adding no cache directive.